# Можно ли сказать "завтрашний день"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Можно ли сказать "завтрашний день"? Или как надо?

Comment: Почему фраза "завтрашний день" вызвала сомнение? Что смутило?

Answer (score 5):

Словообразовательный словарь русского языка в двух томах. А. Н. Тихонов. 1990 (печатный вариант; цифры — это номер словообразовательного гнезда):

**вчера** (439)
вчерась, вчерашний, вчерашнее (сущ.), по-вчерашнему, позавчера, позавчерашний.

**сегодня** (184)
сегодняшний, сегодняшнее (сущ.).

**завтра** (26)
*завтрашний*, назавтра, послезавтра, *послезавтрашний*.

[**Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка**](https://phraseology.academic.ru/3434/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9):
﻿**Завтрашний день**
Разг. Ближайшее будущее.
*Он шёл домой, радуясь тому, что сейчас увидит жену и детей и осчастливит семью известием о премии, полученной за срочный фрахт. Он был спокоен и уверен в завтрашнем дне* (Б. Лавренёв. Срочный фрахт).

Можно сказать не только ***завтрашний***, но и ***послезавтрашний*** — это правильно. Слова употребляются довольно часто:

***Завтрашний день*** от меня, рассуждая практично,
Как ни прикинь на сегодняшний, как ни надень,
Даже гораздо дальше, чем день античный,
Старозаветный и вавилонский день.
И. Лиснянская

*Поэтому отплытие «Дункана» было отложено на **послезавтрашний день** – 20 ноября.*

Answer (score 0):

***Завтра*** ― это (1)наречие и (2) несклоняемое существительное, **завтрашний день и завтра (2) ― синонимы.**

1) И возникает вопрос: **как ими пользоваться?**

Перенести встречу на завтрашний день/на завтра. Давай подождем до завтра/до завтрашнего дня. **Здесь оба выражения применимы, стиль речи только разный (деловой, разговорный).**

2) **На зватра, до завтра** ― обстоятельственные существительные (наречные выражения). Но во всех других случаях, когда требуется **предметное значение и согласование с другими словами**, несклоняемое ***завтра*** становится неудобным и заменяется ***завтрашним днем.***

3) Примеры:

Обещание, данное ею **на завтрашний ден**ь, всего более беспокоило её: она совсем было решилась не сдержать своей торжественной клятвы. [А. С. Пушкин. Барышня-крестьянка (1830)]

О нет, **завтрашний день** уже расписан буквально по минутам. [А. Е. Рекемчук. Мамонты (2006)]

Ночь уплывает, уплывает и **завтрашний день**, уплывут они все, сколько их будет отпущено, и ничего не останется, кроме неудачи. [М. А. Булгаков. Записки покойника (Театральный роман) (1936-1937)]

― Нельзя ли попросить у вас **до завтра** шесть рублей? [Сергей Довлатов. Чемодан (1986)]

Оно висело в виде красного шара над ясным и бодрым морем, обещая **на завтр**а ветер и ещё более резвые, чем сегодня, волны. [Василий Аксенов. Пора, мой друг, пора (1963)]

Answer (score 0):

Да, как уже сказали, такое сочетание вполне корректно в современном языке. Более того, даже "сегодняшний день" (="день сего дня") не считается однозначной тавтологией.

Сразу оговорюсь, что для одного из значений слова день (время суток) никаких ограничений на "завтрашний день" нет в принципе (ср. "завтрашнее утро, вечер"), все остальное говорится только в отношении слова "день" как синонима слова "сутки".

Сомнение вызывает, как я понял, кажущаяся избыточность сочетания (завтра - это уже и так "завтрашний", наступающий день"). И это ощущение не лишено оснований. Раньше, особенно в высоком стиле, подобное выглядело бы косноязычием.

Но тут дело в том, что исходно "завтра" (а также "вчера" и "сегодня") как существительное всегда употреблялось с некоторыми ограничениями, взамен употреблялись конструкции "наступающий день", "нынешний", "минувший". (У Бакланова "День нынешний и день минувший" явно отсылает к комедии Грибоедова, но звучит-то как возвышенно!). И вот именно в такой функции существительного *"наступающий день"* стал естественным образом сейчас заменяться на *"завтрашний день"*, поскольку слова "наступающий", "нынешний" "минувший" уже не столь активно употребляются в разговорной речи.

В переносном значении "завтрашний день" может означать вообще ближайшее будущее - и тут для выражения почти нет альтернативных синонимов. Именно в таком значении плодовитый мем-мейкер Владимир Кличко употребил сочетание в известном афоризме (*"А сегодня в завтрашний день не все могут смотреть. Вернее смотреть могут не только лишь все, мало кто может это сделать."*). Но там употребление "завтрашнего дня" вопросов не вызывает, косноязычие в абсурдности общей семантики фразы.

При этом в наречном значении ("Завтра мы идем в кино") никаких причин для замены на "завтрашний день" не просматривается. Все примеры (включая те, что приводит Римма Михайлова) именно на значение существительного, исключают наречное значения (на вопрос "когда?" не отвечают даже по смыслу, не только по грамматике).

С другой стороны, появление "завтрашнего дня" дело относительно недавнее, поэтому убедительных примеров из классики для иллюстрации изменения стилистической нормы найти сложно. Во всяком случае, я очень сомневаюсь, что подобное было возможно во времена Пушкина.

Итак. В значении существительного (как подлежащее или дополнение) "завтрашний день" вполне законно. В наречном значении ("Завтрашним днем будет хорошая погода") такое употребление избыточно и выглядит чем-то на грани бессмыслицы.

Comment: Со всем согласен, только у Пушкина слова "на завтрашний день" тоже  нашлись (@Jasmin цитировала): *Обещание, данное ею на завтрашний день, всего более беспокоило её: она совсем было решилась не сдержать своей торжественной клятвы. [А. С. Пушкин. Барышня-крестьянка (1830)] *

Comment: М_Г, да, сдаюсь, не посмотрел сразу. Но сдается мне, что тут все-таки какое-то особое употребление. Не синонимичное простому "завтра". Или не совсем синонимичное. Видимо, предлог сказывается. Надо бы по корпусу пробежаться внимательно, буду жив и здоров - попробую.